# CSS Make an image and title align

Tags: html, css

I'm working on trying to create a website, and I want an image to appear to the right side of the title I have picked, but I cant find any way to align them that properly works.

```css
.title {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  width: 680px;
}

.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h1>
    <font size="+10" /><u/>Computer Science A-Level Notes</h1>
  <img class="logo" src="breh.png">
</div>
```

can anyone tell me what I can do?

Comment: Have you tried flexbox or css grid?

Comment: If you are not using bootstrap. Then assign both the heading and image in two different div then use top,left properties to do so.

Comment: @AdamStrauss the tag [tag:twitter-bootstrap] is not involved in this question

Comment: @aloisdgsaysReinstateMonica yeah right!

Comment: You have errors with your tags, for starters `</u>` without a start `<u>` tag *(should have used CSS `text-decoration:underline;`)*. `<font>` is depreciated. You need the parent to have a width that facilitates both Elements.

Comment: as a note, the `font` tag is no longer used in HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to align two elements horizontally. The two modern way to achieve this is to rely on [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) or [css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

Here is a basic usage of flexbox:

```css
.title {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  width: 680px;
}

.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;

}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h1>Computer Science A-Level Notes</h1>
  <img class="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
</div>
```

Related to [Flexbox: center horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.title{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    width: 680px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.logo{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h1>Computer Science A-Level Notes</h1>
  <img class="logo"src="images/1.jpeg">
 </div>
```

Comment: `font` tag is no longer used, might want to consider removing it

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it with flexbox.

```css
.title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
    <h1>Computer Science A-Level Notes</h1>
    <img class="logo"src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59354350/1248177

Comment: @aloisdgsaysReinstateMonica nope! I have used different css properties.

Comment: @ Muhammad well indeed. Still a flexbox solution. A valid alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make both things inside the `.title` class have a `inline-block` alignment, and for the best look you should set the `vertical-align` property on both.

```css
.title {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  width: 680px;
}

.title h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.title .logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h1>Computer Science A-Level Notes</h1>
  <img class="logo" src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
</div>
```

Comment: Nowadays we should use flexbox in most cases. It is quite obsolete to use `display: inline-box` fot this case. For a solution with flexbox, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/59354350/1248177

Comment: I know how to use flexbox. Flexbox is not always needed, and without knowing much else about the OPs particular use case, there's no point in making him look up  something that might confuse them.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without using flexbox 
by simply applying this css

```
.title{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    width: 680px;
}
.title *
{
float:left;
}
.logo{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Avoid using `float: left` without a proper `clear` after. Also you are breaking the css flow. Float is a solution used eons ago. Time to let it die. You should use flexbox instead. It is not difficult to use. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/59354350/1248177

Comment: `@aloisdg says Reinstate Monica `, `float:left;` is here to stay. There are all sorts of situations for using it. Still won't work though, without the `.title` Element `width` to facilitate both Elements. That font was huge.

Comment: @StackSlave most of the time float is use to layout a block. Nowadays, most of the time you have a better way to achieve the expected result.  Thank you flexbox and grid.

Comment: Sometimes you want something on one side or the other, even within a flex.